# How do I bring my work in a new field to the attention of experts?

Tags: research-process, mathematics, conference

I am an expert in mathematics in field A. In recent years I got also interested in another field B, being initially motivated by my field A. I have some ideas in field B and I published 3 papers. The first paper is considered to be really interesting by a number of experts, while the third one is not: the referees of the paper claim that the main result easily follows from some folklore in the field.

I feel that I am working mostly in isolation in field B being in e-mail contact only with a couple of experts. In particular I do not attend conferences in field B and have no chance to present my results to a broader community of experts in B.
Being out of community I have less opportunities to learn most recent results and folklore. In order to make further progress on the ideas I have, it would be most helpful to find collaborators in field B.

What is the best way to change the situation? I believe I have some ideas to offer to experts in B. How can I get a chance to convince them while they do not know me at all? Is it OK to find a relevant conference, write to organizers, send them a brief description of my results, and ask for an opportunity to speak?

Comment: Publishing, that would be the traditional route. Are you looking for more than that? Specify.

Comment: @Aruralreader: As I said I published 3 papers. But I feel that only the referees and a couple more experts are aware of it. Also I would be interested to discuss it with experts in order to know better what is currently known in the field and have more feedback.

Answer (score 7):

The organizers are unlikely to help you much as there is competition for speaking slots at most conferences and the organizers need to be fair. But, you can submit a paper to any conference that accepts them and they will be reviewed. If the paper is good, it might be accepted.

But, the best way, perhaps, is to submit good papers to the journals that those people are likely to read. They will find the papers and through them, find you.

You can also, simply attend conferences in the field and spend your time talking to people, asking questions, and sharing ideas. You aren't likely to go from 0 to 60 in 3 seconds, but you can get there if your work is good.

The people that you are in contact with can also, perhaps, introduce you to others in their circle, thus increasing your own.

Comment: Many conferences don't have that much competition for speaking slots, and many organizers are likely to be accommodating to someone bringing in ideas from a different subfield.